# Python : ImportError in my unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

This is my project structure [image]

Some I've written some unit tests in *tommy/core/tests/test_tprotocol.py*, and in this file, I've this line :

```
from tommy.core.tprotocol import TRequest
```

But when I run unittest in the tests folder :

```
 python -m  unittest tprotocol
```

I've an ImportError :

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tprotocol (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tprotocol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tprotocol'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I always have this type of errors when I import a module from a subfolder...
What is the best way for fix that ?

But everything works if I do `python -m unittest tommy/core/tests/test_tprotocol.py`

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to the line you have shown.

You are currently in the test folder so there's no way you could possibly run `tprotocol` from the terminal from that directory. And you should be using the test module not the original one:

```
python -m  unittest test_tprotocol
```

Comment: `python -m unittest tommy/core/tests/test_tprotocol.py` this work, but this `python -m  unittest test_tprotocol` doesn't